MANTA Recorder Gain File for SoundTrap ST400
I am currently using MANTA for recording I made with a SoundTrap ST400 STD, with the High Pass Filter Off and Gain High.
I am filling in the "recorder information" in the MANTA metadata app for the SoundTrap 400 calibration, but I have noticed they only have a drop down option for the ST300. Are the calibration setting the same for the ST300 and the ST400?
If I compile information for a "custom" recorder (as the ST400 option is not available), a "recorder gain file" is required for the ST400, where can this file be obtained?

I've only dabbled with using MANTA, and my experience is that it is being actively developed, so apologies if this isn't quite what you're asking for or if things can/may have changed since my dabbling.
That said, there is a document on their bitbucket repository alongside code and other examples that explains in detail all the ways MANTA can handle calibrations. I found the document (https://bitbucket.org/CLO-BRP/manta-wiki/downloads/SettingUpCalibrationsForMANTA.docx) alongside code and other examples on their bitbucket download page (https://bitbucket.org/CLO-BRP/manta-wiki/downloads/).
Since links can/do change: here's some relevant excerpts from that doc:

It is expected that recorder manufacturers will provide the nominal calibration files and the necessary information to populate the RecorderTypes.xlsx file. The latest versions of these files may be obtained from the MANTA Wiki.
If a User has a custom acoustic recorder, they may directly enter each of the settings about their recorder directly into the Recorders Panel of the MANTA MetaData App. There is also an option to load the calibration response of the recorder as a two-column calibration file. This file maybe stored anywhere on the User’s computer.
Configuring Hydrophone Types
Hydrophones and Microphones that MANTA knows about are listed in the file ‘SensorTypes.xlsx’ located in the same directory as the MANTA_MetaData_App file. An example of this file is shown in Table 1. The columns of this file are:

Recorder Name: this is the brand name that the recorder is known by. Multiple entries for the same type of unit are possible as long as the sampling rate, maximum input voltage, ADC Bits or calibration files are different. Having one line per recording frequency supported by the device is recommended. This is a free text field. In the MANTA MetaData App, there is not field available for different input filter configurations, therefore the recorder name should specify this option and each filter option should have its own line per sampling rate (for example the SoundTrap lines).
Nominal Calibration File: this the relative path to a ‘.csv’ file that contains the nominal calibration of the recorders. These files have two columns – frequency and sensitivity. For hydrophones, it is expected that the sensitivities will be between -80 and -240 dBV/µPa for hydrophones and ?? for microphones. The path to the files is relative to the directory that contains the MANTA MetaData App. The folder structure that is delivered with the App has each manufacturer’s nominal calibration files in separate folders.
It is expected that recorder manufacturers will provide the nominal calibration files and the necessary information to populate the SensorTypes.xlsx file. The latest versions of these files may be obtained from the MANTA Wiki.
If a User has a custom sensor, or a calibration of the sensor performed at an appropriate facility, there is an option to load the sensitivity as a two-column (frequency, sensitivity) calibration file. This file maybe stored anywhere on the User’s computer.


Good luck, and please let us know how you got on and reply with a self-answer if the data in my response is out-of-date or if you find a different solution yourself.

AFAIK, all the metadata are found in *.xml file that comes with the *.wav files, after decoding the *.sud files. The hydrophone calibration depend on the hydrophones used, which are most likely the same for these models.

My experience with .XML from .sud files is that these do not contain information about the hydrophone calibration. They might contain info about whether gain and/or high-pass filter are applied or not, but it isn't especially clear or obvious how that is represented or should be interpreted. Further, MANTA expects that "Recorder Gain" is provided as a transfer function in a .csv or excel file with a column for frequency and a column for gain). Such information is definitely not in the XML. Previously this info has been provided (maybe by OINZ?) to MANTA for the ST300, but not later models.

If you go the "custom" recorder route and need further calibration information, you can use Ocean Instruments Calibration Database to access the soundtrap calibration record. We have had situations where our instrument was not listed in the database, in which case we reached out to Ocean Instruments to get it added.
Hope this helps!
